# If I have a polynom $p$ with $p(a) = 0$, how to construct a polynom $q$ with $q(a^{-1}) = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If I have a polynom $p$ which has a field element a as its root, i.e. $p(a) = 0$, how can I construct a polynom $q$ from it with $q(a^{-1}) = 0$. I conjecture that Vieta's formulae might be helpful, but for it I need to know all roots, which I don't know in an arbitrary field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$$
p(x) = p_{n} x^{n} + \dots + p_{1} x + p_{0},
$$
you have
$$
0 = p_{n} a^{n} + \dots + p_{1} a + p_{0}.
$$
Now multiply this by $a^{-n}$ to get that the polynomial
$$
q(x) = p_{0} x^{n} + p_{1} x^{n-1} + \dots + p_{n}
$$
has $a^{-1}$ as a root.

Answer (score 2):

See [reciprocal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial).
$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use $q(x)=x^{\deg(p(x))}p\left(\frac1x\right)$. This polynomial will have the same degree as $p(x)$, assuming that zero is not a root of $p(x)$, and it's roots will be exactly $a^{-1}$ for any $a$, root of $p(x)$